# MissingHelperError in Rails::WelcomeController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting the following error after I try creating a new Ruby app with `rails new app-name-1`. When I first run the server with `rails s` I get this:

> AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError in
>   Rails::WelcomeController#index Missing helper file
>   helpers/c:/users/aaa/google drive/web
>   apps/fake_orders_3/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper.rb
>
> Rails.root: C:/users/aaa/google drive/web apps/fake-orders-3

```
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:151:in `rescue in block in modules_for_helpers' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:148:in `block in modules_for_helpers' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:144:in `map!' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:144:in `modules_for_helpers' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:93:in `modules_for_helpers' actionpack (4.2.6) 
lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:108:in `helper' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/railties/helpers.rb:17:in `inherited' railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>' activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require' activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require' activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency' activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require' railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/welcome_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>' activesupport (4.2.6) 
lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:263:in `const_get' activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:263:in `block in constantize' activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each' activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject' activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize' activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:566:in `get' activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `constantize' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:70:in `controller_reference' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:60:in `controller' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:39:in `serve' actionpack (4.2.6) 
lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call' activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call' activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call' activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call' activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__' activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks' activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call' web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call' web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch' web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call' railties (4.2.6) lib/
rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app' railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call' activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged' activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged' activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged' railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call' activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call' actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call' railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call' railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service' C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service' C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run' C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread' This error occurred while loading the following files:   rails/application_controller
```

Comment: Hi, can you please show us relevant code snippets (edit your question and add them there) eg the code from `Rails::WelcomeController#index` which does stuff with a helper file?

Comment: Do you get a different result when using directory names that do not contain embedded spaces?